# How to understand what is required in this task

Tags: c#, interface, delegates

I am working on a task but I can not understand this part of it:

> Define a **delegate bool  GreaterOf(Comparable obj1, Comparable obj2)** 
>   (obj1 is greater than obj2) to compare Comparable objects in terms of
>   SizeOf(); For each of the structs Point,  Vector and Triangle define a
>   private method **GetSizeOf(Comparable obj1, Comparable obj2)** to
>   implement the delegate **GreaterOf** for the respective struct.  Define a
>   property to get the instance of **GreaterOf** for **GetSizeOf()**.

Here, **Comparable** is an interface that has that method declaration:

```
double SizeOf();
```

I have three structs that implement it(Point, Vector, Triangle). In each of these structs I have defined the method **GetSizeOf** as follows:

For the Point struct:

```
private bool GetSizeOf (Point obj1, Point obj2)
    {
        return obj1.SizeOf() > obj2.SizeOf();
    }
```

What I don't understand is this:
**Define a property to get the instance of GreaterOf for GetSizeOf().**

**EDIT:**
If this would help, further on this is what it is in the condition:

> Define a BubbleSort( Comparable[], GreaterOf g)  method to sort an
>   array of Comparable objects, where the delegate GreaterOf determines
>   the ordering sequence (Assume the elements of Comparable[] are all
>   Points, Vectors or Triangles only)

Comment: If it is homework, he's going about it the right way -- in asking for guidance, not someone to write his code.

Comment: It is not a homework. I am just trying to solve that task but this is the part that I couln't get.

Comment: Maybe this is just really confusing method names, but `GetSizeOf` returns a `bool`? And `GetSizeOf` for a point takes two points? That really doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The closest to me is that it has to return the instance that is the greater one from the pair.

Comment: Don't mind me, I'm just wondering about the homework itself - it seems to me that your teacher is not primarily a C# programmer by far. Or at least the sample seems to suggest that - it could of course just be that he couldn't figure out a proper task for you to learn about delegates. Simply said, a delegate is a type that represents a method call (or rather, the signature of the proper method). In C#, you can have a delegate as a return type (or a property), and return an instance of the delegate. You can then eg. save this into a variable, and call it.

Comment: I'd add the code that does exactly what the homework asks for, but I imagine that's not what you want. I'm not sure how to just point you in the right direction without giving away the whole thing. Just do the steps: define a delegate with the given method signature. Create a property in Point, Triangle etc. which returns this delegate type. Return the delegate for the proper method.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your tutor like to have a public property, which point to your private method `GetSizeOf`.

```
public interface Comparable
    {
        double SizeOf();
    }

    public delegate bool GreaterOf(Comparable obj1, Comparable obj2);

    public struct Point
    {
        private bool GetSizeOf(Comparable obj1, Comparable obj2)
        {
        return obj1.SizeOf() > obj2.SizeOf();
        }

        private GreaterOf _pointGreaterOf;

        public Point(object a)
            : this()
        {
            var v = a; //it make no sense as is only there to prove the property assignment.
            PointGreaterOf = GetSizeOf;
        }

        public GreaterOf PointGreaterOf
        {
            get { return _pointGreaterOf; }
            set { _pointGreaterOf = value; }
        }
    }

    public struct Trigangle
    {
        public GreaterOf TrigangleGreaterOf { get; set; }

        private bool GetSizeOf(Comparable obj1, Comparable obj2)
        {
        return obj1.SizeOf() > obj2.SizeOf();
        }

        public Trigangle(object a)
            : this()
        {
            var v = a;//it make no sense as is only there to prove the property assignment.
            TrigangleGreaterOf = GetSizeOf;
        }
    }

    public struct Vector
    {
        public GreaterOf VectorGreaterOf { get; set; }

        private bool GetSizeOf(Comparable obj1, Comparable obj2)
        {
        return obj1.SizeOf() > obj2.SizeOf();
        }

        public Vector(object a)
            : this()
        {
        var v = a; //it make no sense as is only there to prove the property assignment.
            VectorGreaterOf = GetSizeOf;
        }
    }
```